# Filter a chart in Excel with a variable

Tags: excel, vba, filter, excel-charts

Good evening, I look for directions for a problem. I do not include any code here since I look for a general direction first and work my way through the details from there. I'm not an experienced coder but I hope I can make myself clear:

I have build an Excel data input form for customer transactions. For every customer, there is a unique ID in my database. Now I need to build a number of charts that show details for the selected customer (selection via a value from a list, in a combobox), for example their last transactions, the sum total of all their transactions etc.

When I change the customer in the combobox, I want the all charts to change, too.

I have one table (Table1) per chart, which contains all data for that chart. For example, the most recent transaction of every customer in my database.

The easy way to get to the desired result would probably be to build another table (Table2) which I would build with simple VLOOKUPs that filter out the desired customer ID from Table1, with the currently selected customer as lookup value for my formulas. I think I would get this to work.

But would there be a more direct way to do this? Can I select the complete table1 as data for my chart and filter the data with a variable that holds the customer ID that I look for?  I try to avoid table2.

If you good people could name alternative approaches that I could test in addition to my rather daft plan  I would be very grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is out of scope for SO. It's an architecture question. We help solve problems with actual written code that does not work.

Comment: You can try to play with VBA. I've started coding this way: start recording a macro, do what your macro should do, stop the recording, check and reverse-engineer the resulting code. If you get stuck, come back and write down a question with a sufficient sample of your data, the code that you've developed so far, a description of what you are trying to achieve and what is the problem you've encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that you should use a second table, but the second table should be a Pivot Table, based on the original table. The field that you want to filter by should go into the Filters area at the top of the Pivot Table, and the Pivot Table filter is like a combo box. The chart will be a pivot chart based on the Pivot Table, and it will update to show all of the data revealed by the filter.